# change event is not working for select Tag in Angular 8

Tags: angular

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-5" style="float: left; margin: 0">
  <select
    class="select-option"
    #caseTypeList
    (change)="getcaseType($event)"
    name="casetypes{{i}}"
    [(ngModel)]="caseType"
  >
    <ng-container *ngFor="let caseTypes of CaseTypesArray;">
      <option [value]="caseTypes.key">{{caseTypes.value}}</option>
    </ng-container>
  </select>
</div>
```

This Is my Ts file code
In this `getCaseTypeList` Api i'm getting response and that also i stored in `caseTypeList` array after saving these codes...when i'm trying to click on select box the event is not firing... if i add click event then first time of click drop downbox not loading properly and in 2nd click it's loading..

```js
getCaseTypeList() {
  this.caseService.getCaseTypeList({
    data: {
    },
    success: (result) => {
      this.caseTypeList = result.data.caseTypes;
      //this.CaseTypesArray = extend(true,[],this.caseTypeList);
    }
  });
}
getcaseType(args){
  this.CaseTypesArray = [...this.caseTypeList];
  this.caseType = args.target.value;
  this.validSuccess = false;
  this.caseValid = false;
  //this.dataArr.push(this.caseTypeList);
}
```

Comment: guys please help me out of this i tried lot of things but it didn't work.....

Comment: put this in a StackBlitz and demonstrate the problem you have.

Comment: How did you use caseType in select before *ngFor?